# How to capture touch event on a view when enters from another view

Tags: android

I want to capture an event when the user slides his finger from one view to another.

I was able to capture the movement of the finger via the following code

```
view1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "touch listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("touch event", "triggered");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But it only works when the user starts the finger movement from the same view (i.e View1). I want to capture the finger movement in View1 even when the user enters from View2. at least the first event when the user enters View1 would be enough. but the touch event doesn't trigger at all when I move a finger in View1 which comes from View2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    final View view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
    final Rect rectOfView1 = new Rect();
    view1.post(() -> view1.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectOfView1)); // populating the rectOfView1 after the view1 is inflated

    final View view2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);
    view2.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if (rectOfView1.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
            Log.d("view1 event", "triggered");
            return true;
        }
        Log.d("view2 event", "triggered");
        return true;
    });
```